# Vote up/down module undefined constant errors

Tags: 7, rating

I recently have been trying to create a site for people to submit encryption algorithms to be tested. I wanted to make a voting process similar to Stackoverflow.

The best looking module I found was called the [vote up/down](http://drupal.org/project/vote_up_down) module.

I installed it on a fresh install of Drupal 7, along with the [answers module](http://drupal.org/project/answers) and [answers userpoints](http://drupal.org/project/aup), however when I enable it on a question, I get the following error:

```
Notice: Use of undefined constant NODE_BUILD_PREVIEW - assumed 'NODE_BUILD_PREVIEW' in vud_node_node_view() (line 147 of /var/www/crackmycode2/htdocs/sites/all/modules/vote_up_down/vud_node/vud_node.module).
Notice: Use of undefined constant NODE_BUILD_SEARCH_INDEX - assumed 'NODE_BUILD_SEARCH_INDEX' in vud_node_node_view() (line 148 of /var/www/crackmycode2/htdocs/sites/all/modules/vote_up_down/vud_node/vud_node.module).
Notice: Use of undefined constant NODE_BUILD_SEARCH_RESULT - assumed 'NODE_BUILD_SEARCH_RESULT' in vud_node_node_view() (line 149 of /var/www/crackmycode2/htdocs/sites/all/modules/vote_up_down/vud_node/vud_node.module).
Notice: Use of undefined constant NODE_BUILD_RSS - assumed 'NODE_BUILD_RSS' in vud_node_node_view() (line 150 of /var/www/crackmycode2/htdocs/sites/all/modules/vote_up_down/vud_node/vud_node.module).
Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$build_mode in vud_node_node_view() (line 152 of /var/www/crackmycode2/htdocs/sites/all/modules/vote_up_down/vud_node/vud_node.module).
Notice: Undefined variable: a3 in vud_node_node_view() (line 161 of /var/www/crackmycode2/htdocs/sites/all/modules/vote_up_down/vud_node/vud_node.module).
```

and, when I go into the `voting details` tab, I get a WSOD.

Here is a screenshot of the actual error:

[image]

Is this just because I set something up wrong? Is there a library that is missing? Is there a patch that is required to be installed?

Comment: Questions about bugs in modules hosted on drupal.org are off-topic, as per FAQ.

Answer (score 3):

The module page for Vote Up/Down says (emphasis mine):

> 7.x (**unstable, on development, do not use this version for production**)

[`NODE_BUILD_PREVIEW`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/constant/NODE_BUILD_PREVIEW/6) was a constant in Drupal 6. I imagine that the maintainers of Vote Up/Down have branched off of the old D6 version to create the D7 version...and haven't completed the changes yet.

There's not even a dev/unstable release available for download on the module page so you definitely shouldn't be using this module for the time being.

Comment: Is there another good module out there for drupal 7 with the same functionality?

Comment: I was using it because it is required for answer userpoints,

Comment: I don't know of one I'm afraid; I recently tried to install the same stack of modules as you are now and didn't get very far. The problem is *none* of them have a stable release. Apparently [userpoints is a one-of-a-kind module](http://drupal.org/node/723380) so I think your best bet is to ask in the issue queue for either module. Sorry I can't be more help, I'd like this combination of modules to work as well